# MySQL - Moving from 5.7 to 8 issue with altering 'function' to 'job_title'

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

In the past I have been using MySQL 5.7 for a Symfony project.
I have the table 'work_experience' with a column named 'function' this causes an obvious syntax error because 'function' is a restricted word. This has started  since moving to MySQL 8. Now I am trying to alter this column name from 'function' to 'job_title' this is also failing because of the same syntax error. How can I bypass this to solve my issue? This all worked fine on my local machine because I am using MariaDB 10.4 in a Docker container, but now it's failing on production.

I am using doctrine:schema:update because the schema is now several migrations behind because of this bug.

The error:

```
bin/console d:s:u --force

 Updating database schema...

[error] Error thrown while running command "'d:s:u' --force". Message: "An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE work_experience CHANGE function job_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL':

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'function job_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL' at line 1"
```

Doctrine schema validate:

```
bin/console d:s:v

Mapping
-------


 [OK] The mapping files are correct.


Database
--------


 [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

Would dumping and recreating the schema/database work? I have this all setup using Doctrine migrations but I can run manual queries on the production server.
Dumping the database would cause a lot of manual work to recreate some of the data that is critical for the site to function.

Comment: The column names should be *quoted* in the alter command. I gather that the alter command is generated by a schema migration tool that wasn't written by you?

Comment: Thanks @hobbs correct I am using the Doctrine ORM that is included with Symfony.
I have tried this but sadly I get the following error with single and double quotes


`ALTER TABLE work_experience CHANGE "function" "job_title" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL;`

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"function" "job_title" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL' at line 1`

Comment: Try this query ```ALTER TABLE work_experience CHANGE `function` job_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL```

And you should really use migrations instead of using `doctrine:schema:update`.

Comment: Thanks @JulienB. that was the solution! I always use migrations but because this is blocking/being blocked by another issue I am having I have to use the schema update to bypass that.